# AngularJS is removing my $_parent property when the object is passed back to the controller function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-8

I have a linked list of JavaScript objects that I want to generate breadcrumbs from.

Because I'm using the list in recursive directive I need to use $_prev and $_next (instead of prev and next) so I won't get JSON.parse error about circular reference.

```
var myapp = angular.module('myApp', []);

var data00 = { id: 0, label: 'label_0' }
var data01 = { id: 1, label: 'label_1' }
var data02 = { id: 2, label: 'label_2' }

data00.$_next = data01;
data01.$_next = data02;

data01.$_prev = data00;
data02.$_prev = data01;

myapp.controller('testController', function($scope){
    $scope.data = data02;
    $scope.getBreadCrumbs = function(branch){
        var crumbs = branch.label;
        while(branch.$_prev){
            branch = branch.$_prev;
            crumbs = branch.label + ' \\ ' + crumbs;
        }
        return crumbs;
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kyrisu/tDHPP/)

Everything works in chrome, but in IE8 inside getBreadCrumbs function $_prev property does not exist.

Any input how I can debug the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is this `$_prev`? I've never seen it before.

Comment: It is a property that I defined myself. I needed to use $ prefix so angular won't crash while watching a linked list with circular references.

Comment: nvm I understand your code. It's not really optimal though because you have to manually define the prev and next for each object. The more data points you get, the more work.

Comment: @NicolasMoise above code is just a proof of concept - in the application itself $_next and $_prev are mapped to resources.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your IE8 problem but IMHO your approach is not very good. I believe that by using a better approach you will cut down future development/maintenance and quite possibly get rid of your IE8 bug. What I would do is put all your `dataxx` objects into **a single array** and then either use a function or a angular directive(s) to create your breadcrumbs from that array.

I strongly discourage you from doing something like this

```
data00.$_next = data01;
data01.$_next = data02;

data01.$_prev = data00;
data02.$_prev = data01;
```

Because as you add more data points it'll be more unnecessary work. You can either use the length of the array to see if you are on the first/last breadcrumb on or use the `$first` `$last` property that angular gives you on an `ng-repeat`

Comment: Actually data is organized into a tree structure and I need to get from the branch to the root. Because the tree can become really big the branches are filled using resources. For me it seems easier to check if $_child, which in real life is a promise, is resolved or not, than to search through the array (or so I think). Also JavaScript in IE8 is really slow that's why I try to avoid searching through big arrays and just use *pointer* to the parent instead.